# Fit <svg> to the size of <object> container

Tags: css, html, svg, size

I have this markup:

```
#widget1 {
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}

<div class="widget" id="widget1">
    <object data="foo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
</div>
```

I managed to make the `<object>` element fill up the outer `<div>`, but the inner foo.svg file has its own ideas how big it is. I need foo.svg (which consists of an `<svg>` element, of course) to be the same size as `<object>` and `<div>`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is answered (with examples) in the [svg primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#SVG_web).

tl;dr summary:

- remove 'width' and 'height' attributes on the svg root, and add a 'viewBox' attribute with the value "0 0 w h", where w and h are the absolute values usually found in the width and height attributes (note that percentages and other units aren't allowed in the viewBox attribute)

Comment: What if I can't edit the `.svg` file? Can I do it from the html?

Comment: @ColonelPanic It can be done with script if the svg and the html are same-origin. Here's how to get started with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376732/work-with-elements-from-embed-or-object-tag.

Comment: Is it possible to force nested SVG that has own width="300" and height="200" to stretch to fill parent DIV that's 700x500 ?

Answer (score 0):

add this to the parent div

```css
#widget1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to add:

```
width: XXXpx !important;
height: XXXpx !important;
```