# Work with elements from embed or object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, svg, embed

I have an svg graphics inserted in the page with an embed or object tag:

```
<object data="graphics.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="graphics" />
```

The image is loading properly and I can see its SVG structure with the browser debugger. I see all the elements ids and attributes but it seems to me there is no way to select those elements with my scripts on page:

```
$('#graphics path').length; // 0 (jQuery)
$('path').length; // 0 anyway
```

Is it possible to browse the graphics elements as usual?

Comment: I don't know if jQuery can do this itself natively, but a quick Google search produced this plugin that might do the trick: http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will show up as a separate document, similar to an iframe. You can access it like this:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('graphics').contentDocument
```

Note that it is important to wait until the svg file is loaded; you might want to put your code in the `object` element’s `onload` event handler, like this:

```
<object data="graphics.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="graphics" />
<script>
  document.getElementById('graphics').addEventListener('load',function(){
    var svg = document.getElementById('graphics').contentDocument
    // do stuff, call functions, etc.
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I saw this snippet when tried to search for the answer. Now I see it really works but I can not check if SVG object is loaded. Do I have to put something like `$('#graphics').load(function() { /* ... */ }`?

Comment: yes, that should work. I edited with a plain javascript example, but that should work for jQuery.

Comment: Hmm... `$('#graphics')[0].addEventListener('load', function(){})` works, but `$('#graphics').load(function(){})` does not... I saw your final snippet while googling the solution but I did not try it exactly - that is where I made a mistake.

Comment: is it possible to target elements inside the svg (groups, paths) with this method?