# load method jQuery and native JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, load

I have an `object` tag on my page with SVG graphics in it:

```
<object data="graphics.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="graphics" />
```

I would like to execute some code which needs svg file to be completely loaded. So using jQuery I put:

```
$('#graphics').load(function() {
    // some code
})
```

And using native JavaScript I put:

```
$('#graphics')[0].addEventListener('load', function() {
    // some code
});
```

Now the second snippet works and the first does not. What do I miss here?
I supposed `embed` tag would provide another behavior but it seems there is no difference.

Comment: If it works using native JS, why bother with the jQuery stuff?

Comment: I had another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376732/) and then I've just suddenly found this thing which seemed very strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

Caveats of the load event when used with images
A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load() shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with this that should be noted. These are:

- It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
- It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
- It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
- Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

AND:

The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

Answer (score -1):

try something like that

```
var element = $("<object/>");
    element.load(function () {
)};
```

Comment: Mmm, are sure it is somehow connected with my selector? My goal is to 1) Select an element by id 2) Ensure it was loaded 3) Run code. But my exact question is where my two snippets are not the same?