# Why can't I select an <object> with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg

I am having a very hard time selecting the `<object>` tag of my HTML. In my HTML I have a tag like this (in addition to all of the required html):

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/knob.svg"> My image </object>`

To display an SVG file.

The SVG file loads correctly, but when I try **any** selector from Javascript (tagname, querySelector, class, id), they all return this:

Example:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
console.log(a); // returns []
```

I am doing this through Chrome's dev tools so the page has definitelly already loaded.  Similar, the selectors work on other `divs` and such that I have in the page, so I am not sure what is going on.

If I delete all the attributes and just have as a test in my HTML:

```
<object class="logo"> thing </object>
```

selecting that returns a `function anonymous()`

Can somebody tell me if I am doing somethign wrong?

Comment: You need to provide more context.  Doing this: `<html><body><object>foo</object></body><script>console.log(document.querySelectorAll('object'))</script></html>` works fine

Comment: Where did you put the `<script>` tag? Is it before the `<object>` tag?

Comment: Interesting.  Looks like Chrome at least treats 'object' tags at least slightly differently.  Your "`function anonymous()`" is actually a `HTMLCollection` of all the object tags instead of just a `NodeList`.  `document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0]` returns the `HTMLObjectElement` that corresponds to the object.  i.e.  Objects are not really elements

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376732/work-with-elements-from-embed-or-object-tag `<object>` creates a nested document, like an iframe.

Comment: @Barmar I am doing this from the Dev Tools console directly so everything is loaded.

Comment: I think this is a problem with Dev tools, as when I type the same code directly into my HTML it works.